# Windows Phone 8.1 get network usage per seconds

Tags: windows, networking, windows-phone-8, upload, download

I'm coding my WP 8.1 XAML runtime app and I want to get network upload/download bytes in realtime. It's possible to do it and please show me how

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the current API.